Complex analysis by Freitag and Busam exercise 1.5.4.

$f(z) =\begin{cases}e^{-1/z^4},  & \text{For $z\ne 0$} \\0, & \text{for $z=0$ }\end{cases}$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and is complex differentiable for all $z \in\mathbb{C}^0$, but not at the origin.

This is exercise on my book "complex analysis by Freitag and Busam". This is strange since I thought that if a function satisfy Cauchy-Riemann differential equations then it is analytic however this is a clear counter example.
For example the book proved this exercise:

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by f(z) = $f(z)= x^3y^2+ix^2y^3$.
Show: $f$ is complex differentiable exactly on the coordinate axes, and there is
no open subset $D \subset C$ such that $f|D$ is analytic.

By showing that this function only satisfy Cauchy-Riemann differential equations only on the axes.

The solution that was presented by the book for the above exercise:

The function $f$ is obviously analytic on the complement of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. It is unbounded in a neighborhood of the origin, as we can see by considering $z=$ $\varepsilon(1+i)$. So it cannot be analytic in the whole plane. We remark also that the two partial derivatives exist in 0 , they are both zero, so the CAUCHY-RIEMANN equations are satisfied in the entire $\mathbb{C}$. This is because the restriction of $f$ to both axes is rapidly decaying, when one approaches 0 .

I don't know why it is "obviously analytic on the complement of $\{0\}$ ", also this doesn't explain why although CAUCHY-RIEMANN equations are satisfied this function is not analytic at $\mathbb{C}$.

The function $f$ is the composition of two holomorphic functions away from $0$, and so is holomorphic on the complement of $0$. A function that satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations is not enough to say that it is complex differentiable. You also need that the function be real differentiable to conclude that it is complex differentiable. In your case, compute the limit of the difference quotient from two different directions to see that the limit does not exist, and hence $f$ is not real differentiable at $0$.
